# subprocess get result before terminate

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess, python-asyncio, real-time

#### Get Result of a SubProcess in Real Time

I would like to get each result (`sys.stdout`) in real time before the subprocess terminates.
Suppose we have the following file.py.

```
import time,sys
sys.stdout.write('something')
while True:
    sys.stdout.write('something else')
    time.sleep(4)
```

Well, i made some tries with modules of subprocess, asyncio and threading, although all methods gives me the result when the process is finished. Ideally i would like to terminate the process myself and get each result (stdout, stderr) in real time and not when the process it completes.

```
import subprocess
proc = sp.Popen([sys.executable, "/Users/../../file.py"], stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr= subproces.STDOUT)
proc.communicate() #This one received the result after finish
```

I tried as well with readline `proc.stdout.readline()` in a different thread with `threading` module and with `asyncio`, but it waits as well until the process completes.

The only usefull that i found is the usage of `psutil.Popen(*args, **kwargs)` with this one i could terminate whenever i want the process and get some stats for that. But the main issue still remains to get in real time (asynchronously) each `sys.stdout` or `print` of *file.py*, at the moment of each printing.

*preferred solution for python3.6

Comment: Have you tried calling `sys.stdout.flush()` after the ` sys.stdout.write()`. You might also need to add a newline character to the end of the string passed to the latter.

Comment: Thanx4respose. I have already try this with no result. Just think that not even the first `sys.stdout` this couldn't read it and waits until terminates.

Comment: For (near) real-time interprocess communications, you may need to used a [`multiprocessing.Manager`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#managers). Another possibility is a [`mmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mmap.html#module-mmap).

Comment: I preferred to do that without usage of network. I have a variety of options via networking protocol such as twisted, zmq, etc. The core is to catch the `sys.stdout` each time is used via other process.

Comment: Neither of my suggestions require the use of a network — they provide ways to communicate between processes running on the same computer. Just thought of a third one: [`multiprocessing.shared_memory`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html#module-multiprocessing.shared_memory).

Comment: This one is very usefull. But the problem is that each process calls a *module.py* itsn't an internal process, so i need to catch the prints of them. How could i store in shared_memory each print of *module.py* without modify the *module.py* at the moment which i could have the results just when this process is over?

Comment: Unclear what you mean by _calls_ a `module.py`. Depending on how that's done, it might be possible to redirect the `sys.stdout` in each process so output gets written into some sort of  `shared_memory` file. You should try doing it and ask another question if you can't get it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the first and foremost thing is to ensure that your `file.py` program actually writes the data the way you think it does.

For example, the program you have shown will write nothing for about 40 minutes, because that's how long it takes for 14-byte prints issued at 4-second intervals to fill up the 8-kilobyte IO buffer. Even more confusingly, some programs will *appear* to write data if you test them on a TTY (i.e. just run them), but not when you start them as subprocesses. This is because on a TTY stdout is line-buffered, and on a pipe it is fully buffered. When the output is not flushed, there is simply no way for another program to detect the output because it is stuck inside the subprocess's buffer that it never bothered to share with anyone.

In other words, **don't forget to flush**:

```
while True:
    # or just print('something else', flush=True)
    sys.stdout.write('something else')
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(4)
```

With that out of the way, let's examine how to *read* that output. Asyncio provides a nice stream-based interface to subprocesses that is quite capable of accessing arbitrary output as it arrives. For example:

```
import asyncio

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
        "python", "file.py",
        stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE, stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE
    )
    # loop.create_task() rather than asyncio.create_task() because Python 3.6
    loop.create_task(display_as_arrives(proc.stdout, 'stdout'))
    loop.create_task(display_as_arrives(proc.stderr, 'stderr'))
    await proc.wait()

async def display_as_arrives(stream, where):
    while True:
        # 1024 chosen arbitrarily - StreamReader.read will happily return
        # shorter chunks - this allows reading in real-time.
        output = await stream.read(1024)
        if output == b'':
            break
        print('got', where, ':', output)

# run_until_complete() rather than asyncio.run() because Python 3.6
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: @szZzr Good point; the program I tested it with never exited so I didn't notice the issue. I've now edited the answer to include (a slightly different) EOF detection.

Comment: First of all thnx a lot for your solution... Your code is working with some changes for python 3.6 and at your function `display_as_arrives ` you could modify the following while-statement `while not stream.at_eof()` to receive data of `file.py` until its EOF for this situation never ends.

Comment: @szZzr Note: I rejected the suggested edit because Python 3.6 supports async/await (it was introduced in **3.5**), so `yield from` and `@asyncio.coroutine` shouldn't be needed. Also, I actually *tested* the code in the answer with Python 3.6, and it worked. If you have issues with it, please let me know in a comment and we can work to fix it.

Comment: I m apologise you have absolutely right! You could keep just the EOF and `readiline()` to avoid the problems of `read()`. Thnx a lot.  :)

Comment: @szZzr Note that `readline()` will insist on reading full lines, so it won't be "real-time". The code in the answer will pick up even the prints that do not contain newlines (as long as the subprocess ensures they are actually printed, i.e. flushes them), as issued by the code snippet in your question.